# How to check Alamofire library version?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, xcode7.3

I implemented Alamofire using cocoapod.I am using Xcode7.3.1.
My podfile is like the following way

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'ALamoWeather' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for ALamoWeather
pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

How to check which Alamofire library version is used?
Please help me.

Comment: By doing this, you are installing the latest version.

Comment: Check `pod file.lock`

Comment: If you do not mention the version in your podfile explicitly, it means you have the latest version in your project. Just go to Almofire website and see what the latest version is

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open `Podfile.lock` in textedit. You will find the version of `Alamofire` and other used third parties' version.

Snapshot of one of my pod file.lock:-

PODS:

```
  - AFNetworking (2.6.3):
    - AFNetworking/NSURLConnection (= 2.6.3)
    - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (= 2.6.3)
    - AFNetworking/Reachability (= 2.6.3)
    - AFNetworking/Security (= 2.6.3)
    - AFNetworking/Serialization (= 2.6.3)
    - AFNetworking/UIKit (= 2.6.3)
  - AFNetworking/NSURLConnection (2.6.3):
    - AFNetworking/Reachability
    - AFNetworking/Security
    - AFNetworking/Serialization
  - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (2.6.3):
    - AFNetworking/Reachability
    - AFNetworking/Security
    - AFNetworking/Serialization
  - AFNetworking/Reachability (2.6.3)
  - AFNetworking/Security (2.6.3)

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  AFNetworking: cb8d14a848e831097108418f5d49217339d4eb60
 COCOAPODS: 0.38.2
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply open your project, then select the pod and you will get to see the installed pod version.

[image]